# Sinatra/Haml: How to execute Ruby code inside Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, haml

I'm writing a Sinatra + Haml app, and in my Javascript code, I want to be execute some Ruby. In erb, the following works:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() {
    <% @persons.each do |person| %>
        $("#<%= person.id %>").attr("style", "<%= person.style %>");
    <% end %>
  });
</script>
```

But how would I write this in Haml? I tried something like

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    - @persons.each do |person|
      $("##{person.id}").attr("style", "#{person.style}");
  });
```

But the Ruby code gets rendered as code instead of getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. Basic string interpolation seems to work, but nothing complex. What I've adopted is:

```
-v = "##{person.id}").attr("style", "#{person.style}"
:javascript
  $(function() {
    - @persons.each do |person|
      $(#{v});
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    #{- @persons.each do |person|}
      $("##{person.id}").attr("style", "#{person.style}");
  });
```

Comment: I get a "syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_DEND" when I try this. Any tricks to this?

Comment: sorry..  can't remember exactly what my thought process was around this back then..    nowadays, I would probably just try to find a different way to accomplish whatever it was, as this approach is pretty messy and unmaintainble

Answer (score 0):

take a look a this post, maybe It could be helpfull.

[Ruby methods within Javascript within HAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640863/ruby-methods-within-javascript-within-haml)