# Inline Variables in JS Script for HAML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

So I've written this code for erb awhile ago

```
<% if @posting.pictures.blank? %>
<% else %>
    <script>
        $("#slider-posting").vegas({
            slides: [
                    <%- @posting.pictures.each do |p| %>
                        {src: '<%=p.url%>'},
                    <%- end %>
            ],
            transition: 'slideLeft'
        });
    </script>
<% end %>
```

I'm having a bit of trouble converting it to HAML.

Trying conversion based on http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/

```
- if @posting.pictures.blank?
- else
  :javascript
    $("#slider-posting").vegas({
                slides: [
    <haml_silent>                    @posting.pictures.each do |p| 
    </haml_silent><haml_block>                      {src: '#{p.url}'},
    </haml_block>           ],
                transition: 'slideLeft'
            });
```

Causes the following error

*undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass*

on this line

```
</haml_silent><haml_block>                        {src: '#{p.url}'},
```

Comment: try http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/

Comment: i did, i don't believe the conversion went too well though. Editing post to show results + test

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640863/ruby-methods-within-javascript-within-haml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
- if @posting.pictures.blank?
- else
  :javascript
    $("#slider-posting").vegas({
      slides: [
        #{
          @posting.pictures.map { |p| "{src: '#{p.url}'}"}.join(',')
        }
      ],
      transition: 'slideLeft'
    });
```

Comment: I'm getting this while trying your code:

undefined method `-@' for #<String:0x007f8435903e70>

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried omitting **?** after if statement, it's normally used when you're using ternary operator in your code, so please try omitting that part and try again.

Comment: That ? is part of the method name `blank?`